# Beeline and hive connection on single Node Hadoop Cluster

Tags: java, database, hadoop, hive, beeline

I am new with bigdata , hive and hadoop. i have just installed hadoop and hive on my ubuntu machine following the steps given by https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-hadoop-single-node-hadoop-cluster

Currently how i connect to hive is by going to hive directory and using cmd : `hive`
This will then allow me to create my db and tables.

i am also unsure if im having hiveserver2 but currently i installed hadoop 2.7 and hive 2.1 on my ubuntu machine

i did not install sql or oracle db as im just using hive, should i install this to connect with beeline?

What i am trying to achieve is by connecting to my hive using beeline. I was wondering if there is any additional steps needed or should there be any configuration needed.
What i am trying now is

1.) after start-all.dfs
2.) i will then run this command :  beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default

[image]

But i am getting this error on connection refused.

1.) should i change my localhost to my machine ip address, i check ifconfig , my inet is e.g inet 192.168.1.222 
2.) should i change  beeline -u jdbc:hive2:/hadooplocalhost/default to my hadoop localhost
[image]

my hive environment :
[image]

i am using Single Node Hadoop Cluster for study and practice purpose
i am trying to connect to my hive using beeline. but im unsure on how can this be done. Is there step by step tutorial on how i can connect using beeline after hadoop and hive installation

Answer (score 0):

You can just use either of the following to connect without specifying any ip's.

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://  [Or]
hive/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://
```

When it asks for username and password just press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your HS2 isn't running.
In case you haven't already initialised metastore with some other RDBMS(MySql/Oracle/Postgres etc), you can try derby:
Do:

```
bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

Then if you want to run in embedded mode:

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://
```

Else, If you want to launch Hs2:

```
bin/hiveServer2 &
```

And then you can use your same beeline command:

```
bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

Make sure to have properly configured HIVE_HOME & the hive configs...